# Core 2 Application Root Empty When From Nuget Packet

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, nuget

The code in the **GetApplicationRoot()** method is identical to the code in the WildHare **IOExtensions.GetApplicationRoot()** method.

If the code is referenced in the same solution using a project reference in a .net Core 2 project, they return the same value. In a **net471** project, both lines also return the same application root.

In .net Core 2, if I use the **IOExtensions.GetApplicationRoot()** method imported from the Nuget WildHare packet, it returns an empty value.

Just to be clear, I am the author of the package and was surprised when this did not work in the context of a .net Core Nuget package and am interested in the why.

Any ideas?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using WildHare.Extensions;

namespace FirstCore
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"GetApplicationRoot(): { GetApplicationRoot() }");
            // Returns C:\Code\Samples\Core2\FirstCore

            Console.WriteLine($"IOExtensions.GetApplicationRoot(): { IOExtensions.GetApplicationRoot() }");
            // Returns empty string

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static string GetApplicationRoot()
        {
            var exePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
            var appPathMatcher = new Regex(@"(?<!fil)[A-Za-z]:\\+[\S\s]*?(?=\\+bin)");
            var appRoot = appPathMatcher.Match(exePath).Value;

            return appRoot;
        }
    }
 }
```

[image: Result]

Comment: I guess the question should be, why you would use an extension only used by a couple of hundred developers at most (according to nuget gallery statistics) to do a job that standard .net libraries hands you for free at the same abstraction level.

Comment: Because I am the writer of the extension library and would like to understand why it does not work in this instance. My understanding was that the above way was a decent way to get the application root so I was surprised that it did not work when used in the context of a Nuget dependency.

Comment: Btw, thanks for the comment. Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value returned from `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase` is not always what you expect it to be and therefore it won't match the regular expression, which results in an empty string.

`Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly` resolves the assembly that contains the code that is currently executing, which here is the WildHare assembly.

While developing a `.NET Core` application, any assemblies referenced via `NuGet packages` don't get copied to the `bin` folder.
This means that the WildHare assembly gets resolved from the `NuGet packages` folder, having a codebase like eg. `file:///C:/Users/you/.nuget/packages/wildhare/0.9.8.3/lib/netstandard2.0/WildHare.dll`
This path doesn't match the regular expression, giving an empty string as result.

When building a `Full .NET Framework` application (eg. 4.7.1), all assemblies do get copied to the `bin` folder, which results in a regex match.

When having the code inline in your main assembly, the codebase path will of course include the `bin` folder and will pass the regex.

Use [`Assembly.GetEntryAssembly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getentryassembly?view=netcore-2.1) instead of `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly`, as `Assembly.GetCallingAssembly` returns the assembly that is the process executable in the default application domain, or the first executable that was executed, *which is your main application*.

*Remark: do note that because of the regular expression match in your implementation, `GetApplicationRoot` will only be effective if the application is running from within a `bin` folder, which will be very unlikely once an application is published. Either relax or remove this constraint.*

Comment: That makes sense. I appreciate your insight!